# Send mail after deleting django Model

Tags: django-views, django-forms

I've been using `send_mail()` for when someone creates a Group (model) or updates it, but I've been having trouble figuring out the function for deleting.

This works for when someone creates a Group:

```
class CreateGroup(CreateView):
    model = Group
    form_class = GroupForm
    template_name = 'create_group.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save()
        account = self.request.user.account
        send_mail (
            f"Thanks for creating {instance.name}",
            'create group',
            NOTIFICATION_EMAIL,
            [account.user.email],
            fail_silently=False
            )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('group_detail', args=[str(instance.pk)]))

class UpdateGroup(UpdateView):
    model = Group
    form_class = EditGroupForm
    template_name = 'update_group.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save()
        account = self.request.user.account
        send_mail (
                f"Thanks for updating {instance.name}",
                'update group',
                NOTIFICATION_EMAIL,
                [account.user.email],
                fail_silently=False
            )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('group_detail', args=[str(instance.pk)]))
```

That works, but how do I do it for DeleteView:

```
class DeleteGroup(DeleteView):
    model = Group
    template_name = 'delete_group.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Is there something like `form_valid()` for DeleteView? Or does `form_valid()` work for those views as well if there's a form associated. I assume a view needs a form for form valid and I thought there wasn't a form since I'm just deleting a Group.

Comment: As of Django-4.0, a `DeleteView`  subclasses the `FormMixin`, and thus has a `form_valid` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something like `form_valid()` for `DeleteView`?

As of [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0), a [**`DeleteView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView) uses the [**`FormMixin`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin), and thus has a [**`.form_valid(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid). It works with a simple `Form`, that has no fields, and this is thus only used to simplify the logic, and will let Django validate the CSRF-token, and then delete the object.

Since [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0), you thus can use `.form_valid(…)`:

```
# since Django 4.0

class DeleteGroup(DeleteView):
    model = Group
    template_name = 'delete_group.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        send_mail (
            f'Thanks for deleting{self.object}',
            'delete group',
            NOTIFICATION_EMAIL,
            [self.request.user.email],
            fail_silently=False
        )
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Before [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0), you can override the [**`.delete(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeletionMixin.delete), and send the email, so:

```
# beforeDjango 4.0

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class DeleteGroup(DeleteView):
    model = Group
    template_name = 'delete_group.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        send_mail (
            f'Thanks for deleting{self.object}',
            'delete group',
            NOTIFICATION_EMAIL,
            [self.request.user.email],
            fail_silently=False
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

For deleting you send a POST or DELETE request to the view.

Comment: i get a ```type object 'super' has no attribute 'form_valid'```

Comment: Interesting. ```send_mail()``` works and I get an email, but then I get the error above, and the Group remains not deleted.

Comment: @Eddy: sorry, I made a typo. Fixed.